# Angular Material Select set default first option

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wish to set "pizza-1" value on top of select option, the array is variable and is not possible for me create an order array. So it's important for me do this from html template.
Is there a way to specify an option to be the first option by default ?

Component file

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  selected: any = -1;

  foods= [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

}
```

Template

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you're trying to order the mat-options from the given array of objects you need to sort the array as follows.

1. In your array / options list change
   `{value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},` to `value: {food: 'Steak', val: 0}, viewValue: 'Steak'},`

**Why?
Objects provide efficient structuring of data rather than strings.**

```
foods= [
    {value: {food: 'Steak', val: 0}, viewValue: 'Steak'},
    ....
  ];
```

2. Sort your array with JS Sort

```
this.foods.sort(function(a, b){
  var x = a.value.val.toLowerCase();
  var y = b.value.val.toLowerCase();
  if (x < y) {return -1;}
  if (x > y) {return 1;}
  return 0;
});
```

That's it and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Select does not have a way to set a particular value as the first option. This will have to be addressed in the code.

Since you don't get the an ordered array, you will have to create one. One approach to do this, would be to create a 2nd array. Splice the object with 'pizza-1' into this, followed by the remaining objects.